# Prove Optimal Line Derivation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vectors, least-squares

In class we learned how to derive the optimal line approximated by given points.

There are different ways to approach. We looked at it in a more algebraic way, using matrices and I'm having trouble doing a derivation:

Given some points $\{x_1, \cdots, x_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$.

$$
\tag 1
(\mathbf{u},\boldsymbol{\mu}) \leftarrow arg min \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} || \underbrace{ \boldsymbol{\mu} + \langle \mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu},  \mathbf{u} \rangle  \mathbf{u}}_{\mathbf{\widehat{x}}_i} -  \mathbf{x}_i ||^2 \right]
$$
$$
\tag 2
= \left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} || \left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^{T} \right)  (\mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu})||^2 \right]
$$

Where $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ are line variables and $\mathbf{\widehat{x}}_i$ is the projected point of $\mathbf{x}_i$ onto the line.

So we are trying to find the line that minimizes the distances from all the points. What I don't understand is how we can manage to derive $(1)$ into $(2)$.

The hint is to use the identity $\langle \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{u} \rangle \mathbf{u} = (\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^{T})\mathbf{v}$.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: There's a typo in the last formula: it should be $$
\left[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} || \left( \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{u} \mathbf{u}^{T} \right)  (\mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu})||^2 \right]
$$

Comment: @Aretino thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

$$
\boldsymbol{\mu} + 
\langle \mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu},  \mathbf{u} \rangle  
\mathbf{u} -  \mathbf{x}_i =
\langle \mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu},  \mathbf{u} \rangle  
\mathbf{u} -  (\mathbf{x}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})= 
(\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T)(\mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu}) - \mathbf{I} (\mathbf{x}_i-\boldsymbol{\mu})
=(\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^T-\mathbf{I})(\mathbf{x}_i - \boldsymbol{\mu}).
$$